# Error: "could not find implicit value for parameter readFileReader" trying to save a file using GridFS with reactivemongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.1, reactivemongo

I am trying to save an attachment using reactivemongo in Play 2.1 using the following code:

```
def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.file("carPicture").map { picture =>
    val filename = picture.filename
    val contentType = picture.contentType

    val gridFS = new GridFS(db, "attachments")
    val fileToSave = DefaultFileToSave(filename, contentType)

    val futureResult: Future[ReadFile[BSONValue]] = gridFS.writeFromInputStream(fileToSave, new FileInputStream(new File(filename)))

    Ok(Json.obj("e" -> 0))
  }.getOrElse {
    Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
      "error" -> "Missing file"
    )
  }
}
```

I am getting the following error:

could not find implicit value for parameter readFileReader: reactivemongo.bson.BSONDocumentReader[reactivemongo.api.gridfs.ReadFile[reactivemongo.bson.BSONValue]]
[error]       val futureResult: Future[ReadFile[BSONValue]] = gridFS.writeFromInputStream(fileToSave, new FileInputStream(new File(filename)))

What am I missing?

Thanks,

GA

Comment: What version of reactivemongo are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely you don't have the DefaultReadFileReader implicit object in scope, which you can fix by adding an import:

```
import reactivemongo.api.gridfs.Implicits._
```

The following compiles fine for me (using the Play 2.1 reactivemongo module, version 0.9):

```
package controllers

import java.io.{ File, FileInputStream }
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Future

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.libs.json._

import reactivemongo.api._
import reactivemongo.bson._
import reactivemongo.api.gridfs._
import reactivemongo.api.gridfs.Implicits._

import play.modules.reactivemongo.MongoController


object Application extends Controller with MongoController {

  def index = Action {
    Ok(views.html.index("Hello, world..."))
  }

  def upload = Action(parse.multipartFormData) { request =>
    request.body.file("carPicture").map { picture =>
      val filename = picture.filename
      val contentType = picture.contentType

      val gridFS = new GridFS(db, "attachments")
      val fileToSave = DefaultFileToSave(filename, contentType)

      val futureResult: Future[ReadFile[BSONValue]] = gridFS.writeFromInputStream(fileToSave, new FileInputStream(new File(filename)))

      Ok(Json.obj("e" -> 0))
    }.getOrElse {
      Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
        "error" -> "Missing file"
      )
    }
  }
}
```